# Erro ao tentar fazer um redirecionamento por .htaccess em uma sub pasta no Laravel 5.2

Tags: htaccess

estou usando minha aplicação em Laravel 5.2 em uma subpasta wwww.dominio.com/aplicacao/

mas não gostaria que o "/public/" ficasse na frente, estou usando da seguinte forma no .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Depois ao acessar a url recebo o seguinte erro:

```
NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:
```

Acredito que deve ser algo simples de resolver mas não sei como, alguma sugestão?

Comment: Acrescente a rota que era suposto aceder sff, como está a definir em routes.php? Experimenta `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1`, com a `/` antes do public

Comment: Ao adicionar a barra antes recebo :"Not Found
The requested URL /public/ was not found on this server" acredito que não é problema na rota só no .htaccess